# What does the % function do in python?

Tags: python

What does the  percentage

> %

function do in python in a line such as

`x % 2`

Comment: It's an operator not function.

Comment: Not _this_ many downvotes guys, s/he's a newbie.

Answer (score 4):

In this context it is the modulus, or [remainder in the math sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder).

So `7 % 2 == 1` because when you divide 7 by 2, you get a remainder of 1.
Similarly, if you wanted the fact that 2 goes into 7 three times, `7 // 2 == 3`

---

The context is important, because `%` can also be used for [old-style string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

In that context, `'%s to %s' % ('A', 'Z')` would return a string `'A to Z'`

However, don't use `%` for string formatting in python today. Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 2):

This is called the modulus operator, it gives you the remainder after division:

```
>>> 5 % 2
1
>>> 44 % 3
2
>>>
```

Comment: Just for completeness, if `x` is a string then `%` is used for string formatting.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Please edit my answer then, and add your name to the mix, you thought of it first :P I always use `.format` :P

Comment: If `x` is some other arbitrary object, it executes the `__mod__` method, which could do anything.